# Firestore doc Update with Merge true

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Today while working on Cloud Firestore using Admin SDK, I accidentally forget to replace .update with .set with merge true option and to my surprise the query worked and document got created. I removed merge:true and then I got document not exists error. I tested it again with merge:true and document created again. I could not find anything about this in documentation. Can anybody explain this behavior.

```
let query = userRolesRef
           .doc(user).update(
                    {
                      isDeliveryPerson:true
                    },
                     { merge: true }
                );
```

Comment: You are right, using the Admin SDK it creates a new doc (I've verified it in a Cloud Function). I've thoroughly looked at the Node.js [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#update) and I don't see any reason why it shoudl do that, even if, with the Node.js Admin SDK the `update()` method can take several parameters. I would suggest you contact Firebase support and/or you post in this Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk

Answer (score 4):

There is **no** difference between using `.update` and `.set` with merge true option for documents that already exist in your collection. The difference between these two operations comes only for documents that do **not** exist. For instance, `.set` with merge true option will create the document if the document does **not** exist, while when using and `.update`, the operation will fail.

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo, the OP has actually detected that when using `update()` the way he explains in his question and **with the Admin SDK**, it **does create** a doc (even if this doc was not existing before, surprisinglly calling `update()` creates the doc without any error). I've verified it in a Cloud Function and it is actually the case.

Comment: Hey Renaud. Hm, are you sure? Before answering, I read the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) that stays: *Updates fields in the document referred to by this DocumentReference. The update will fail if applied to a document that does not exist.*.

Comment: Hi again Alex, yes I am sure! I've thoroughly tested it and much to my surprise, it works. PS: note that the doc you link in your comment is the one of the JS SDK, not of the Admin SDK.

Comment: In that case, definitely contacting the Firebase team will be the best solution. Yes, the [right docs](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#update), are the ones linked in your comment. Copied and paste from another bookmarked page.

Comment: @AlexMamo I also read same in documentation but as Renaud has clarified the document got created while using update with merge true. I will write to Firebase team.

Comment: @DeependraSolanky Good to hear that. Please let us know the answer from the Firebase team when you receive it.